# Quiero agregar un checkbox a un formulario de registro, en la vista previa se ve pero al generar la app desaparece

Tags: angular, ionic, ionic-framework

estoy tratando de ayudar a un amigo con un leve cambio en un formulario de registro de una app creada en Ionic5 + Angular 10. No conozco ninguna de las dos plataformas pero encontré la forma de modificar el formulario html para agregar el checkbox y una vez marcado ese dato viaja correctamente a la API de registro.

[image: formulario de registro modificado]

El gran problema que encuentro al compilar la aplicación es que el checkbox desaparece. Prove de eliminar la carpeta www y hacer un nuevo build antes de abrir el proyecto en android estudio, sin exito.
El resultado en el emulador es este:

[image: formulario de registro compilado en el emulador]

El codigo html del formulario en [codeshare](https://codeshare.io/PdJNVo)

Alguna idea de como solucionarlo? Gracias desde ya!

Comment: ¿El proyecto usa Cordova o Capacitor?

Comment: Hola, usa Capacitor

Answer (score 0):

Tiene pinta de ser algo con las dimensiones o está Hidden en el código, si no muestras código poca gente puede ayudarte.

Comment: Evita dejar comentarios en la zonas de respuesta, espera a que tengas la reputación necesaria para poder comentar, date una vuelta en [answer].

Comment: Ahi modifique la pregunta para incluir el codigo de formulario en codeshare. Si hace falta algo mas quedo disponible. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

< div class="form-group form-check">
< input type="checkbox" id="Terms_and_Conditions" name="Terms_and_Conditions" value="x" class="form-check-input" required>
< label for="Terms_and_Conditions" class="form-check-label">  I have read and accept the terms and privacy< span style="color: red; cursor: help;" title="Required"> *< /span>< /label>

< a href="https:// Terms and Conditions . html "< /a>

< /div>

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).